# Issue on executing different query inside same Controller function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Here I have function `index` which is having two different model calls as follows:
**CONTROLLER:**

```
function index()
{
    $people = $this->M_results->search_people(); // first model method call 
    // print_r($people); //shows result
    $skills = $this->M_results->get_skill($category_name); // second model method call 
}
```

**MODEL:**

```
function search_people()
{
    $this->db->select("registration,gender,profile_img,location");
    $this->db->from('search_result');
    $this->db->join('services','search_result.registration = services.reg_id','left');
    $this->db->join('review','search_result.registration = review.reg_id AND review.active = 0','left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}

function get_skill($category_name)
{
    $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(skills.id ORDER BY skills.name ASC) as id,GROUP_CONCAT(skills.name ORDER BY skills.name ASC) as skill,sub_categories.name as sub_cat,class');
    $this->db->from('skills');
    $this->db->join('sub_categories','skills.sub_cat_id = sub_categories.id');
    $this->db->join('categories','sub_categories.cat_id = categories.id');
    $this->db->where('categories.name',$category_name);
    $this->db->where('skills.active',0);
    $this->db->group_by('sub_categories.name');
    // echo $this->db->get_compiled_select(); exit();
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return  $query->result();
}
```

**Now the problem is that, the call to `search_people` is returning exact result.**

But on running the second model call i.e to `get_skill` function, the select query of `get_skill` is including the columns of select query in `search_result` function. And shows the below database error:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'registration' in 'field list'
>
> SELECT registration, gender, profile_img, location,GROUP_CONCAT(skills.id ORDER BY skills.name ASC) as id, GROUP_CONCAT(skills.name ORDER BY skills.name ASC) as skill, sub_categories.name as sub_cat, class FROM skills JOIN sub_categories ON skills.sub_cat_id = sub_categories.id JOIN categories ON sub_categories.cat_id = categories.id WHERE categories.name = 'Child and Pet Care' AND skills.active =0 GROUP BY sub_categories.name

**In the above query you can see both columns in `search_people` and `get_skill`.**

Comment: concatenate table name before these fields : registration, gender, profile_img, location

Comment: you mean like `search_result.registration` ? But it fires the same error!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer for future references.

**Resets the current Query Builder state. Useful when you want to build a query that can be cancelled under certain conditions.**

`$this->db->reset_query();`

I found the solution from below link:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::reset_query